# Does Lightstreamer .NET adapter support 64-bit?

Tags: c#, 64-bit, lightstreamer

I've been googling this topic for several hours with zero success. I even posted to the LS forum but they are silent on this question, which is surprising.

So I'may hoping that someone in the SO community might have the answer.

Does the Lightstreamer .NET adapter support 64-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody had any fast answers, I decided to answer my own question.

I ran the following command to see if the DLL was built specifically with an x64 or x86 flag:

`corflags DotNetClient_N2.dll`

I got the following result:

```
Version   : v2.0.50727
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 0x1
ILONLY    : 1
32BITREQ  : 0
32BITPREF : 0
Signed    : 0
```

The `PE` flag says PE32, but the `32BITREQ` field is set to 0, which indicates to me that the DLL can be used against an x64 platform build.

I tested the DLL against a test project targeting x64 and was able to run it successfully. I'm going to post this up in case anyone else has the same question with hopes they find this useful.